# Is it possible to schedule a tweet?

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

Is it possible to schedule a tweet using Tweepy?

I could not find any mention to the datetime, referring to the code I use to create a tweet in tweepy:

```
api.update_status(tw_post)
```

If it is not possible, which workaround would you suggest to schedule tweets using python?
Thanks

Comment: Well, as long as your script is running, you can do a loop to sleep until your desired time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [twitter-api-client](https://github.com/trevorhobenshield/twitter-api-client) library, and do something like this:

```
    account.schedule_tweet(tweet, date)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `datetime` to check for the current time:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 18)
    api.update_status(tw_post)
```

If the hour on your computer is 18, the code will run.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  How is this "scheduling" anything?

Comment: It tweets at 18:00, so the tweet it's *scheduled* for 18:00

Comment: @MateiPiele thanks, but I agree with CryptoFool. I need to find an effective way to schedule tweet properly like in Buffer or TweetDeck. Buffer in the past could be a solution, but now it doesn't allow to create app any more. Otherwise this library could have been interesting maybe: https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-python